# How to find my own service?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-service

I would like to find my own service (`RadarService`) in the activity -- to check if the service is running or not.

However the naming is, errm, a bit confusing and I am lost. In order to start a service I create intent:

```
 this.radarIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(RadarService));
```

So I tried to extract the name of the service from this intent and use it for comparison -- but `Class` property returns the name of the class of the intent itself, `Type` property is empty.

Ok, so I tried to use `typeof(RadarService).ToString()` -- this give me the string `MyNamespace.RadarService`, nice. But when I tried to match it against the list of running services I failed, because my service is listed as `md5--here-comes-md5-hash--.RadarService` (it is set as `ClassName` and `ShortClassName` in `ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo`).

So how to find out my own service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeof` is going to give the `C#` type / name, you want the auto-generated  `Java` *Android Callable Wrapper* class of that C# type so you can get its `CanonicalName`.

```
Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(StackOverFlowService)).CanonicalName)
```

Example:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(StackOverFlowService));
StartService(intent);

var serviceName = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(StackOverFlowService)).CanonicalName;
var manager = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(ActivityService);
foreach (var item in manager.GetRunningServices(int.MaxValue))
{
    if (item.Service.ClassName == serviceName)
        Log.Debug("SO", "Service is running!!!");
}
```

You can avoid the auto MD5-based Java class naming that `Xamarin.Android` does by hardcoding a name via the `Name` parameter on the ACW-based class attribute:

```
[Service(Label = "StackOverFlowService", Name="com.sushihangover.WickedApp.StackOverFlowService")]
[IntentFilter(new String[] { "com.sushihangover.StackOverFlowService" })]
public class StackOverFlowService : Service
{
~~~
}
```

Now your Service Java class name would be `com.sushihangover.WickedApp.StackOverFlowService` instead of `md58b0fd40f68fa0d8c16b76771789ed62a.StackOverFlowService`

Comment: Thank you very much! Also for the info about attributes for the service.